# Can't access vector on the heap

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, stl

I have a vector in the heap, but can't get its elements - it doesn't compile - gives n error 'cannot bind 'std::basic ostream'  Stack vector and simple array work fine.  What is wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<int> * factors= new vector<int>(4);
    cout<<factors<<endl;
    cout<<(factors+1)<<endl;
    //cout<<factors[1]<<endl;

    factors->push_back(12);
    factors->push_back(232);
    factors->push_back(54);
    factors->push_back(42);

    //cout<<*factors; //error - cannot bind 'std::ostream..' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream...'
   // cout<<factors[0]; // error

        //vector in stack
    vector<int> factors3(4);
    factors3.push_back(43);
    factors3.push_back(543);
    factors3.push_back(64);
    factors3.push_back(26);
    cout<<"factors3 "<<factors3[3]<<endl; //gives "0"
    cout<<"factors3 "<<factors3.at(3)<<endl; //gives "0"

    int * factors2=new int[10];
    factors2[0]=32;
    factors2[1]=35;
    factors2[2]=676;
    factors2[3]=123;
    cout<<factors2[0]<<endl; //it's OK
    cout<<factors2[1]<<endl;
    cout<<*factors2<<endl;

    cout << "Done" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the lines that are causing the compiler errors. First, this one:

```
cout << *factors << endl;
```

Here, `factors` is a `vector<int>*`, so `*factors` is a `vector<int>`. This code therefore tries to insert a `vector<int>` into a stream. You can't use the `<<` operator to display a `vector<int>` in C++ (it doesn't come with an overloaded `<<` operator), so the compiler error you're getting here means "I see that you're trying to use `<<` to output a `vector`, but I don't know how to do that."

You might wonder, then, why the code

```
cout << *factors2 << endl;
```

works correctly. In that case, `factors2` is an `int*`, so when you dereference `factors2` by writing `*factors2`, you're getting back an actual honest-to-goodness integer, which can indeed be printed out. Notice that raw arrays and `vector`s work differently in this regard - in C++, pointers to arrays are just pointers to the first element of the array, so dereferencing them yields a pointer to the first element, while a pointer to a `vector` is *not* the same as a pointer to its first element.

This also explains why writing

```
cout << factors[0] << endl;
```

doesn't work. Remember - `factors` is a pointer to a `vector`, and a `vector` isn't an array. Writing `factors[0]` means "give me the first `vector` in the array pointed at by `factors`," not "give me the first element of the `vector` pointed at by `factors`. If that's what you want to do, you can write

```
cout << (*factors)[0] << endl;
```

This says "dereference `factors` to get back the actual `vector`, then look up its zeroth element."

As for your second question - why aren't you seeing the numbers you added to the vector? - notice that you declared the vector by writing

```
vector<int> factors3(4); // <--- Notice the 4
```

The `(4)` here means "give me a `vector` initialized to have four `int`s, all of which are zero." When you then use `push_back`, you're adding new elements to the `vector` rather than replacing the existing elements. You can fix this either by directly writing to the vector elements:

```
vector<int> factors3(4);
factors3[0] = 43;
factors3[1] = 543;
factors3[2] = 64;
factors3[3] = 26;
```

or by not specifying a size for `factors3`:

```
vector<int> factors3; // <--- No 4!
factors3.push_back(43);
factors3.push_back(543);
factors3.push_back(64);
factors3.push_back(26);
```

or, if you have a modern compiler, by initializing the vector like this:

```
vector<int> factors3 = {43, 545, 64, 26};
```

In either words, you're mixing and matching two different approaches - each of which would work individually - but which together don't do what you expect them to do.

To summarize:

- You can dereference a pointer to an array to get a pointer to the first element, but this doesn't work with pointers to vectors.
- Be careful about default-sizing a vector and then using `push_back` - it's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Thank you. It's all very clear now. But what if I have a vector of vectors of ints? `vector< vector<int> > * pointer = new vector< vector<int> >() `? The pointer would point to the external vector, then we dereference it we get the external vector and to get int we need to `(*pointer)[0][0]`, right? Or If it is `vector< <vector<int>> * > * pointer2`, the int is `(* (*pointer2)[0] )[0]`?

Comment: When in doubt, look at the types! If `pointer2` is a `vector<vector<int>>*`, then `*pointer2` is a `vector<vector<int>>`. If you use square brackets to select something from a vector, you get back something of the underlying type. This means that `(*pointer2)[a]` is a `vector<int>`, so `(*pointer2)[a][b]` would be an `int`. Using that approach, how would you pick something out of `pointer2` if it were a `vector<vector<int*>*>*`?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> cout<<(factors+1)<<endl;
> //cout<<factors[1]<<endl;
> ```

should be:

```
cout << (*factors)[1] << endl;
```

---

> ```
> vector<int> factors3(4);
> factors3.push_back(43);
> factors3.push_back(543);
> factors3.push_back(64);
> factors3.push_back(26);
> cout<<"factors3 "<<factors3[3]<<endl; //gives "0"
> cout<<"factors3 "<<factors3.at(3)<<endl; //gives "0"
> ```

Because you create a vector with 4 elements and then push 4 more, so you'll end up with a vector with the elements `0, 0, 0, 0, 43, 543, 64, 26`

Comment: Thanks. Why is it that in case of simple array in heap the name of the array can be used with brackets without `*` operation and vectors' name can't?

Comment: Because vectors are not arrays and your pointer contains a vector, not an array of vectors. Read about `pointer arithmetic` and `operator []` to understand the details how they work.